# Join two tables with geometry column into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables that are exactly the same. I want to join them together into one large dataset. I tried simply `SELECT-INTO` query but got an error...

```
SELECT * INTO dbo.ParkingBay 
FROM (SELECT * FROM dbo.ParkingBay_Old 
      UNION 
      SELECT * FROM dbo.ParkingBay_New) AS PARKING_BAY;
```

The error is:

> The geometry data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is
>   not comparable.

Comment: Can you use a UNION ALL instead of UNION?

Comment: Could you convert your comment as an answer? I would check this as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UNION performs a DISTINCT on the combined result set.

UNION ALL eliminates this DISTINCT step, but would create the possibility of dupes in the result.

If you are OK with dupe possibility, then try this

```
SELECT * INTO dbo.ParkingBay 
FROM (SELECT * FROM dbo.ParkingBay_Old 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT * FROM dbo.ParkingBay_New) AS PARKING_BAY;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `ALL` solves everything:

```
SELECT * INTO dbo.ParkingBay 
FROM (SELECT * FROM dbo.ParkingBay_Old 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT * FROM dbo.ParkingBay_New) AS PARKING_BAY;
```

Comment: NICE!  You took Sparky's comment and made it an answer to your own question and got the +1!